# Change video timestamp on non-rooted device?

Tags: sd-card, file-system, video, file-management

I thought I'd be clever and compress some old video files taken with my phone camera using the [Video Dieter 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.outplaylab.VideoDiet2) app. It worked fine, except the new files have new (random) names and their `modified` timestamps are set for todays date. Result - they all appear to be shot today when browsing the gallery app.

I need some way to either set the file `modified` timestamps to the correct dates, or set some type of metadata date on the video files.

The phone in question is a Huawei GR5 (Honor 6x) running Android 7.0.

I have tried using Total Commander but it says it can't modify the files, even when I copy them to the internal phone memory. I also tried using the ADB shell to `touch -c -m -t` the files, but I get a `touch: bad '201708211200': Value too large for defined data type` error. Possibly because my phone is not rooted.

I also tried copying them to my Macbook (using Android File Transfer) and altering their timestamps there, but of course they revert to todays date when transferring them back.

Is there a way to set the date (either the file `modified` timestamp or a metadata field) for video files? There are a lot of apps that can modify EXIF data for photos, but it seems to be near impossible to do this for video files without a rooted device...

The last resort I can think of is to take out the SD card and put it in my laptop (Mac) and directly alter the files, but I'm a bit cautious about doing that since the last time I did it (like 7 years ago on a Windows machine and a Nexus One phone) the phone could no longer find most of the files on the SD card afterwards... but perhaps this is a 100% safe operation nowadays?